# How to change version code after AGP 7.0.0-alpha15

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-7.0

Before AGP 7.0.0-alpha15 I could change version code of an app for example like that

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    applicationVariants.all {
      if (buildType.name == "debug") {
        outputs.forEach { output ->
          (output as? com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl)?.versionCodeOverride = 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`applicationVariants` seems missing after AGP 7.0.0-alpha15, how to change it?

PS: It seems ok in plain gradle, above is Kotlin

**Edit**

With answer from [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67413654/6151601) I was able to override version code in build:

```
android {
  androidComponents.onVariants { appVariant ->
    if (appVariant.buildType == "release") {
      appVariant.outputs.forEach {
        it.versionCode.set(1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [`ApplicationVariant`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/variant/ApplicationVariant) still exists and has `List<VariantOutput>`.

Comment: In plain gradle yes, but not in Kotlin DSL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Variant API is going to change to a lazily-evaluated model in AGP 7.0.0, and it seems like Alpha 15 has removed the old APIs for this now. Going forward, you will need to use the `androidComponents` DSL, which gives access to variants. I am not sure if you'll be able to rewrite the version code like this, however. Check out `beforeVariants` and `onVariants` for more info:

```
android {
  androidComponents.beforeVariants { variantBuilder ->
    // Callback before variants are built. Can be modified, but doesn't allow access to outputs
  }
  androidComponents.onVariants { variant ->
    // Callback after variants are built. Apparently it's read-only access at this point, but outputs are available here
    println(variant.outputs)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java plugin code, one can set the version code & name alike this:

```
class SomePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("UnstableApiUsage")
    public void apply(@NotNull Project project) {
    
        ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtension androidComponents = project.getExtensions()
                .getByType(ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtension.class);
    
        androidComponents.finalizeDsl(extension -> {
            for (AndroidSourceSet sourceSet : extension.getSourceSets()) {
                System.out.println(sourceSet.getName());
            }
        });
    
        int versionCode = 1;
        String versionName = "1.0.0";

        VariantSelector selector = androidComponents.selector().all();
        androidComponents.onVariants(selector, variant -> {
            for (VariantOutput variantOutput : variant.getOutputs()) {
                variantOutput.getVersionName().set( versionName );
                variantOutput.getVersionCode().set( versionCode );
                System.out.println(">>>> " +
                        variant.getName() + " " +
                        variantOutput.getVersionCode().get() + " / " + 
                        variantOutput.getVersionName().get());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

`finalizeDsl` happens before `onVariants`.

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    // ..
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
    // ..
}

androidComponents {
    onVariants(selector().all()) { appVariant ->
        for (VariantOutput variantOutput : appVariant.getOutputs()) {
            def versionCodes = ['[armeabi]'       : 100000,
                                '[armeabi-v7a]'   : 200000,
                                '[x86]'           : 300000,
                                '[arm64-v8a]'     : 400000,
                                '[x86_64]'        : 500000]
            String abi = variantOutput.getFilters().identifier;
            Integer version = versionCodes.get(abi) + versionCode
            if (appVariant.getName().contains("Debug")) {
                version += 10000
            }
            variantOutput.getVersionCode().set(version);
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ...
}
```