# Share Android.variantFilter for all app modules

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-build-flavors

I would like to use the same implementation for the `android.variantFilter(...)` for all my android apps modules.

Currently I have such a variantFilter in the "app"-Module which works fine:

```
android.variantFilter { variant ->
    String buildType = variant.buildType.name
    String flavor = variant.getFlavors().get(0).name

    if ((buildType == 'debug' && (flavor == 'canary' || flavor == 'int' || flavor == 'prd')) ||
            (buildType == 'release' && (flavor == 'dev' || flavor == 'loc')))
        variant.setIgnore(true)
}
```

The app contains several modules however and I would like to filter the variants in *all* modules likewise. Without having to reimplement the same variantFilter in all module's `build.gradle` files.

So my question is: is there a way to define that filter in a central place (for example the app's top level `builg.gradle` file) and to cite it in the module specific `build.gradle` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either put the script in a file called `variants.gradle` in the parent directory and [apply it](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins):

```
apply from: '../variants.gradle'
```

---

Or use [`AndroidComponentsExtension.beforeVariants`](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/variant/AndroidComponentsExtension#beforevariants)

> At this stage, access to the DSL objects is disallowed, use `finalizeDsl` method to programmatically access the DSL objects before the `VariantBuilderT` object is built.

and [`DslLifecycle.finalizeDsl`](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/variant/DslLifecycle#finalizeDsl(kotlin.Function1)) (the only option available):

> API to customize the DSL Objects programmatically after they have been evaluated from the build files and before used in the build process next steps like variant or tasks creation.

Which means, that variants can be programmatically configured, without declaring them explicitly. See this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71420033/549372)... it's possibly not `variant.setIgnore(true)` but `variant.enabled = false`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, been out of office for holiday ...
Simple is beautiful. I like the approach using a separate file to define the build variants. Currently testing.

Comment: The mere issue seems that this incubating API is accessible in Java (plugin code); so far not managed to access it in Groovy. And with the script plugin, one can still manage it without redundant code... when doing so, one can also define global variables in the `buildscript.ext` block.

Comment: I am going with the simple solution of using a separate variants.gradle file to centralize variant definition and filter logic. I can even set default values in there which can be overridden in the module specific build.gradle files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want to achieve at the top level build.gradle or is this what you already have:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {
        debug{...}
        release{...}
    }
    productFlavors {
        canary {...}
        int {...}
        prd {...}
        dev {...}
        loc {...}
    }
    variantFilter { variant ->
        String buildType = variant.buildType.name
        String flavor = variant.flavors*.name
        
        if ((buildType == 'debug' && (flavor == 'canary' || flavor == 'int' || flavor == 'prd')) ||
                (buildType == 'release' && (flavor == 'dev' || flavor == 'loc')))
            variant.setIgnore(true)
    }
}
```

There is more info on the official developer.android webpage: [Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#groovy)

Comment: The product flavors are not defined on top level, but inside the modules, so a level further down. So one definition per module inside the module specific gradle file.